# Indicator applet - appmenu - crashes on startup

Tags: 10.10, appmenu

Basically, every time I log in, indicator appmenu crashes and needs to be reloaded. Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: Yo probably need to find out why it's crashing to not need to reload it. Alternatively you could just remove it from the panel so it can't crash. But then you won't have it at all.

Comment: Try creating a new account and seeing if the problem persists there.  It is most likely a config issue.

Comment: You can avoid creating an account by switching to guest mode and test that.

Comment: OP are you still looking for an answer? If so, you may need to repost your question as this is flagged for closure. Regards,

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).